# No puedo eliminar un archivo luego de abrirlo en Python

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código que abre un archivo para enviarlo por un bot de Telegram, pero luego lo elimina del servidor:

```
#  2. Descargar PDF
with open(f'analisis/{filename}.pdf', 'wb') as writer:
    writer.write(file_pdf)   
#  3. Esperar 10 segundos a que descargue el archivo
time.sleep(10)
#  4. Enviar el archivo por telegram 
bot = '''botbotbot'''
doc = open(f'analisis/{filename}.pdf', 'rb')
bot.send_message(chat_id, f'Analisis encontrado para el usuario: {user}, contraseña: {password}')
bot.send_document(chat_id, doc)
#  5. Esperar 10 segundos a que envie el archivo
time.sleep(10)
doc.close()
#  6. Eliminar el archivo del servidor
remove(f'analisis/{filename}.pdf')
```

El error que recibo es:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado por otro proceso: 'archivo.pdf'
```

No logro encontrar la solución.

Comment: No creo que sea parte de los procesos del programa. Es aparte.

Comment: Y si pasaron 10 segundos y no subio? esa clase no tiene algo que te diga que realmente ya termino de subirlo?

Comment: Diego ¿cual es el nombre del archivo? o ¿que tan largo es?

Comment: S @gbianchi también pensé en es detalle que la carga sea mayor a 10 segundos. Lo resolveré más adelante.

Comment: y si justamente el problema es ese? creo que debrerias mirar por ahi.... probaste poner 30 segundos o un minuto y ver si asi funcionaba? si funciona, ese es el problema...

Comment: @CalumRakk el nombre se extiende a este formato: 12345678_A1A1A1A1.pdf

Comment: @gbianchi acabo de agregarle a 50 segundos y ya no lanza el error, pero el tiempo de espera es muy largo, el archivo de envía casi al instante, no entiendo por qué debe esperar tanto tiempo. Pero gracias por la ayuda. Si no encuentro otra solución, esta será la indicada.

Comment: lo indicado es averiguar cuando el archivo fue cerrado.. no es solo el envio.. es que pasen todos los paquetes, que se cierre la conexion, que la clase devuelva el archivo, que el sistema operativo declare el archivo como sin uso... lo ideal, para mi gusto en estos casos.. es no poner un sleep.. si no, probar abrirlo, hasta que se pueda.. en ese momento, ya se libero...

Comment: O sino con un while True: try: #code except: pass, hasta que se pueda